# Trees on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$ with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, inclusion-exclusion

> 1) How many trees on these vertex have at least 2 leaves ?
>
> 2) How many trees on these vertex have more than 2 leaves ?

**Attempt -**

I will use inclusion-exclusion for both cases -

$1)$ $$\binom{8}{2}\cdot6^6-\binom{8}{3}\cdot5^6 + \binom{8}{4}\cdot4^6 - \binom{8}{5}\cdot3^6 + \binom{8}{6}\cdot2^6 - \binom{8}{7}$$

I exclude from the "universe" where 2 of my vertices are leaves.

2) My problem now is when I have at least 3 leaves, and using the same method $$\binom{8}{3}\cdot5^6 - \binom{8}{4}\cdot4^6 +\binom{8}{5}\cdot3^6 -\binom{8}{6}\cdot2^6 + \binom{8}{7}$$

**Is everything true ? thank you !**

Comment: I am not sure I understand how you get your formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, a tree is connected, and it is a classical result that a tree with at least two vertices has at least two leaves.

Hence 1. is simply asking for the total number of trees on $8$ vertices, given by [Cayley's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula):

$$8^6=262144$$

Now a tree has exactly two leaves if and only if it is linear, and such trees almost correspond to permutations on $8$ elements, the only caveat is that each tree corresponds to two permutations (since the trees are not supposed to be oriented). Hence there are $$\dfrac{8!}{2}$$ such trees, and so $$8^6-\dfrac{8!}{2}=241984$$ trees with more than $2$ leaves.